# How to send() an image by saving it in char string in ANSI C? Problem with casting

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm writing my own server in ANSI C (on Linux) and I've got one problem with sending images to a web browser. I'm using the function "send()" to send it and it required a char *. So I was reading a file char by char (using fgetc), I used fread and fgets, but everything had a problem with casting the content(int in most cases) to a bufor - some bytes still were missing (e.g 2008 was send instead of 2020). I think there is some problem with conversion, but I used sprintf and wchar_t and it is still not working.

I've got a function:

```
void send_www(char *buff, int cd){      
if(send (cd, buff, strlen(buff), 0) < 0) {
        perror ("send()");
        exit (1);
```

which I use here:

```
//  while (fread(znak, sizeof(char), i,  handler) != 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    a = fgetc(handler);
    sprintf(znak, "%ls", a);
    send_www(znak, cd);
    }
```

where i is the length of the image file, znak is the char* (in this version wchar_t*). You can also see my earlier try of using fread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `strlen()`. `strlen()` stops and returns the size after it reaches a `\0` byte. Images and binary data are allowed to have a byte valued zero anywhere, so `strlen()` is useless in those cases.

You need to modify your function to:

```
send_www(unsigned char *buff, size_t buf_len int cd);
```

And pass the image size to it, so you can safely `send()` it with the appropriate size.

In your case, it seems you are sure it is a `wchar_t` string, use the appropriate function,  `wcslen()`, not `strlen()` :)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without more details - can you post some code?

One thing is to make sure you open the image file with **the binary option**, e.g. fopen(filename, "rb");

If you're just reading a binary file and sending it to a socket where the other end is expecting binary you should not need any casting or sprintf.

You seem to be confusing char type with strings.  A C string is a sequence of characters that is zero terminated.  Your image file is a binary file containing a sequence of characters but it is not a string.  The send() function takes a pointer to a sequence of bytes, not strings.  To illustrate this look at this sequence of chars (or bytes):

```
255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255
```

In some image file formats this can be three RGB pixels, so white, black white.  9 bytes.  Can be held in a char buffer[9] .  If you call strlen() on this you will get the result 3.  strlen() counts until it sees a zero character.  If you read these bytes from a file without the binary flag it may get transformed and you may get less or more bytes than are really in the file (depending on the contents, the OS etc.).

Rough explanatory code follows:

```
char buffer[1024];
FILE *infile = fopen("test.gif", "rb"); // open a file (check for failure in real code)
int nread = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, infile);
// assume socket is connected (check for number of bytes sent or error in real code)
send(socket, buffer, nread, 0); 
fclose(infile); // close the file
```

To read from a binary file and send the data out to a socket you need to do something like the snippet above.  You would probably keep reading until you reach the end of file, the snippet only reads once.  Also in real code you should check to see how many bytes were actually sent (in the return value from send) and keep calling send until you've sent all the data or an error has occured.

Comment: But the problem is that while sending I have to cast it to a char - or maybe there is another function than send() that I could use to send it without casting? I added some code, maybe it will help.

Comment: Opening the file in binary mode is a good idea.  Your C runtime library is probably doing something funny with bytes that it thinks are newlines or carriage returns.  You could compare the actual file and the file that your server sent and figure out the first byte where they differ.

Comment: It's quite interesting, because when I was using fread() with "1" as a size when the third argument was 1, it sent about 2020 bytes, when the length was 2 - a little bit less, when it was "length" it send about 8 bytes. While sending the conversion(?) is adding - i don't know how to call it - a "0" byte, like here: http://i.imgur.com/ZHuVv.png

Comment: @Anna: it's OK to read one character at a time.  Just slower.  If you want to do that you need to pass a pointer to that character (e.g. &a) to send() and a length of 1 to send just that character.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the problem is that your image data contain characters (`\0`), so they aren't being sent because you're using `strlen()` to figure out how much data to send.

Comment: Not exactly, I've got my own function using fseek and ftell and the size is the same as my Windows describe it. But the amount of send data is smaller than this size.

Comment: The thing is, if you call `send_www()` with a `buff` that happens to have a null character in it, it's going to tell `send()` that the buffer length is `0` - so `send()` won't send anything.

Comment: And what does Windows have to do with anything?  You said this is on Linux - if Windows is involved, make sure your image file is being opened in binary mode so that you don't potentially lose `\r` characters when the runtime tries to do line ending conversion.

Comment: I'm using putty, sorry for a mind short-cut. Actually, it's really problem with strlen(), it's quite late in my country and I didn't realize about what function you're talking about. Thank you a lot, now all images display properly.